# how to change the lengthindicator to display on top right position of phonetextbox, is there a VerticalAlignment property to set?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I have tried the below style (from [Define the style for PhoneTextBox in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534032/define-the-style-for-phonetextbox-in-windows-phone)) but the verticalalignment does not work:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneTextBoxStyle" TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border x:Name="LengthIndicatorBorder">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LengthIndicator" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                     <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I am using the control like this:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox LengthIndicatorVisible="True" DisplayedMaxLength="10" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the position of the length indicator, you just need to change the parmeters ib  the visual state of LengthIndicatorVisible (particularly the change of Translate transform and margin):

Here is the complete style to make the indicator show on top (just the default PhoneTextBox style where I removed the code I mentioned before, the way to retrieve the default style is  in visual studio to go in Outline windows, click right on the PhoneTextBox,  -> Template -> Edit a copy):

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneTextBoxStyleIndicatorOnTop" TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="Text">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="white"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LengthIndicatorStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="LengthIndicatorVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0, 27, 0, 0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="-32" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LengthIndicatorHidden">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.350" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.350">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="LengthIndicatorBorder">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LengthIndicator" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="HintBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="HintContent" Background="Transparent" Content="{TemplateBinding Hint}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Style="{TemplateBinding HintStyle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ActualHintVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="TextBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBox x:Name="Text" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ActionIconBorder" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="84">
                            <Image x:Name="ActionIcon" Height="26" Source="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}" Width="26"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MeasurementTextBlock" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="8" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and just set the style on your control:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox LengthIndicatorVisible="True" DisplayedMaxLength="10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxStyleIndicatorOnTop}"/>
```

Comment: I am not using any of those style in my code, the only style code i have applied is the one in my question.

Comment: Didn't you say you use the style in the link of your question? The part I put in my answer is inside this style

Comment: Otherwise update your question with the full style you are using, in your question itself you just have a few line of the style and not a complete style

Comment: Where you interested with having the default style but with just the length indicator in top right or style which always have a dark style like in the link (but with the length indicator in top right ) ?

Comment: i am just interested to have the length indicator on the top right instead of the default bottom right. I have a big textbox on the screen for the user to add notes and when the keyboard popups up the length indicator gets hidden behind the keyboard so i want to move that top right of the phone textbox.

Comment: I tried your code, but this is displaying in top right corner inside the textbox and not outside the textbox. So when i start typing that indicator hides. The default it displays outside the textbox in the bottom right , I want the same exact way just top right.

Comment: Updated the style in order of the length to show outside the Text box